# class not functioning methods properly

Tags: python, regex, class, methods

I defined a class to handle blocks of tweets so I could manage them a little easier

```
class twitter_block(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.tweets = []
    self.df = pd.DataFrame()

    self.tag = ''
def load(self, data):

    self.tweets = [x for x in data]
```

then defined a method as part of a pipeline:

```
 def clean(self):

    HTTP_PATTERN = '^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*'
    AT_PATTERN = '@\w+ ?'

    # tke away links
    self.tweets = [re.sub(HTTP_PATTERN, '', str(x), flags=re.MULTILINE) for x in self.tweets]
    # take away @ signs
    self.tweets = [re.sub(AT_PATTERN,'',str(x)) for x in self.tweets]
```

but when I call this:

```
tweet = load_data('The_Donald.json')
block = twitter_block(tag='donald')
block.load(data=tweet)
block.clean()
block.print()
```

it returns the 1504 tweets that I loaded into the block object same as before, no cleaning links or anything. Although, actually it does remove @ signs... but this method,

```
def smilecheck(self):
    #save a tweet if there is a smiley there
    smiley_pattern = '^(:\(|:\))+$'
    for tweet in self.tweets:

        if re.match(smiley_pattern, str(tweet)):
            pass
        else:
            self.tweets.remove(tweet)
```

does not remove the tweets without smileys, returns 1504 tweets, the same as I put in... any help guys? im sure this is a problem with the way I am approaching objects

Comment: Is that your actual indentation or have you failed to transcribe it correctly? Please reproduce your indentation carefully, because badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using re.match() instead of re.search()

Where you want to find the tweets that contain a smiley anywhere in the tweet, re.match() searches only from the beginning of the string.

See [python -- re.match vs re.search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346076/python-re-match-vs-re-search)

Comment: re.search seems to give me less tweets (704 vs 1504) but no smileys in them for some reason

Comment: Try moving the "pass" into the else statement and then moving the "self.tweets.remove(tweet)" into the if statement.

Comment: the output still has no smilies in it and it just returns the tweets strangely